# Implement Custom Cost function in keras which requires output of whole batch-size

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, keras

Brief info about the data-set:- 
Its a person Re-ID problem(whether 2 images are same or not) and i have to write my own loss/cost function(binomial Deviance) for its implementation.
For a batch size of 128 i will have 256 images and thus a 3 256*256/batch matrix 
my doubt is how to get the output for a batch-Size using keras so i can implement the cost function

I have added the screenshot of formula of Binomial Deviance Cost function.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpcfe.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your custom loss with an additional `batch_size` argument:

```
def my_loss_template(y_true, y_pred, batch_size):
    # compute the loss
```

To use it,

```
batch_size = 20
my_loss = lambda x, y: my_loss_template(x, y, batch_size)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_loss)
```

Comment: Thanks will try to implement and get back to you.